# Database Connection default not configured in Typo3 v8 UnitTest when testing ViewHelper

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, typo3, typo3-8.x

I migrated from Typo3 v7 to v8. I also have some tests which work fine after some adjustments. However, one test still fails.

I have a UnitTest which tests a ViewHelper, if the provided values in `$this->templateVariableContainer->get('settings')` are properly processed in the ViewHelper.

My testfile:

```
namespace SomeVendor\Extension\Tests\Unit\ViewHelper;

use Nimut\TestingFramework\TestCase\ViewHelperBaseTestcase;
use SomeVendor\Extension\ViewHelpers\ContactFormViewHelper;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\TemplateVariableContainer;


class ContactFormTest extends ViewHelperBaseTestcase {

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    protected $viewHelper;

    protected function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(ContactFormViewHelper::class);
        $mock->setMethods(['renderChildren']);

        $this->viewHelper = $mock->getMock();
        $this->injectDependenciesIntoViewHelper($this->viewHelper);
        $this->viewHelper->initializeArguments();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testExcludes() {

        $renderingMock = $this->getMockBuilder(\TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext::class);

        $templateVariableContainerMock = $this->getMockBuilder(TemplateVariableContainer::class);
        $templateVariableContainerMock
            ->getMock()
            ->method('get')
            ->withAnyParameters()
            ->willReturn([
                'exclude' => ['foo', 'bar']
                ]
            ]);

        $renderingMock
            ->getMock()
            ->method('getTemplateVariableContainer')
            ->willReturn($templateVariableContainerMock);

        $this->viewHelper->setRenderingContext($renderingMock);

        // foo, bar should be excluded in ViewHelper
        // and the array should only contain ['foz', 'baz']
        $resultsCleaned = [
            'foz', 'baz'
        ];

        $this->assertEquals($resultsCleaned, $this->viewHelper->render();
    }

}
```

The ViewHelper which is tested:

```
namespace SomeVendor\Extension\ViewHelpers;


class ContactFormViewHelper extends \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper {

    const VALID_FIELDS = [
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'foz',
        'baz'
    ];


    /**
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function render() {

        $retval = [];

        // get settings defined in TS Setup
        // comma separated, eg: foo,bar
        $settings = $this->templateVariableContainer->get('settings');

        if (isset($settings['excludes']) ) {
            $settings = preg_split('/,/', $settings['excludes']);

            if (is_array($settings) === false) {
                $settings = [];
            }

        } else {
            $settings = [];
        }


        // include exclude magic here
        // resulting array $retval contains only values which are NOT excluded

        return $retval;
    }
}
```

My test run call as follows:

```
/var/www/html/vendor/bin/phpunit -c /var/www/html/vendor/nimut/testing-framework/res/Configuration/UnitTests.xml /var/www/html/typo3_app/typo3conf/ext/extension/Tests/Unit/ViewHelper/ContactFormTest.php
```

This test always fails with the following error:

```
RuntimeException: The requested database connection named "Default" has not been configured.
```

Why even is a database connection needed here? Because of the cache? It worked in Typo3 v7.

**My environment:**

- PHP 7.1.15
- Typo3: 8.7.18
- Nimut Testing Framework: 4.0
- PHPUnit: 6.5.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my migration process was not completly compatible to Typo3 v8 yet. Since the method `getTemplateVariableContainer` is [deprecated](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.0/Deprecation-69863-DeprecateGetTemplateVariableContainerFunction.html) this could be the root of that that the database connection is not initialized.

I updated my testfile as follows, with this configuration all tests are green:

```
namespace SomeVendor\Extension\Tests\Unit\ViewHelper;

use Nimut\TestingFramework\TestCase\ViewHelperBaseTestcase;
use SomeVendor\Extension\ViewHelpers\ContactFormViewHelper;
// use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Variables\CmsVariableProvider instead of TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\TemplateVariableContainer;
use TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\Core\Variables\CmsVariableProvider;


class ContactFormTest extends ViewHelperBaseTestcase {

    /**
     * @var \PHPUnit_Framework_MockObject_MockObject
     */
    protected $viewHelper;

    protected function setUp() {

        parent::setUp();

        $mock = $this->getMockBuilder(ContactFormViewHelper::class);
        $mock->setMethods(['renderChildren']);

        $this->viewHelper = $mock->getMock();
        $this->injectDependenciesIntoViewHelper($this->viewHelper);
        $this->viewHelper->initializeArguments();
    }

    /**
     * @test
     */
    public function testExcludes() {
        // completly remove the setting of the templateVariableContainer through the renderingContext and set it directly through the setVariableProvider, don't forget to call injectDependenciesIntoViewHelper($this->viewHelper) afterwards

        $CMSvariableContainer = $this->getMockBuilder(CmsVariableProvider::class);
        $CMSvariableContainerMock = $CMSvariableContainer->getMock();
        $CMSvariableContainerMock
            ->method('get')
            ->withAnyParameters()
            ->willReturn([
                'exclude' => ['foo', 'bar']
            ]);

        $this->renderingContext->setVariableProvider($CMSvariableContainerMock);
        $this->injectDependenciesIntoViewHelper($this->viewHelper);

        // foo, bar should be excluded in ViewHelper
        // and the array should only contain ['foz', 'baz']
        $resultsCleaned = [
            'foz', 'baz'
        ];

        $this->assertEquals($resultsCleaned, $this->viewHelper->render();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The DB config structure has changed in TYPO3 Version 8.1

There is a changelog regarding this breaking change available at [Breaking: #75454 - LocalConfiguration DB config structure has changed](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/8.7/Changelog/8.1/Breaking-75454-LocalConfigurationDBConfigStructureHasChanged.html)

Comment: Already got that, I adjusted the array structure to the new one. Other FunctionalTests which require a DB connection work so I don't think this answer is related to my problem.

Comment: The error occurs if $GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']['Connections'][$connectionName] where $connectionName = 'Default' in your case is empty. If you have adjusted your connection settings, this might be a problem with your cache I guess.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the cache. I cleared all caches and deleted the typo3temp directory but the error still occurs.

Comment: var_dump($GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['DB']) indeed delivers an array without the default db configuration: array(1) {
  'additionalQueryRestrictions' =>
  array(0) {
  }
}

Comment: Link is broken (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/core/Changelog/8.1/Breaking-75454-LocalConfigurationDBConfigStructureHasChanged.html)